# MUI DataGrid pinned columns

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, grid

I'm trying to lock the "actions" column to the right in my grid.

Is there a way to do this in the free version (MUI DataGrid, **not** DataGridPro)?

Answer (score 0):

```
initialState={{ pinnedColumns: { right: ['actions'] } }}
```

please try adding this property to your datagrid.

Comment: It seems doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is only available in pro+ version for the Data Grid